# ADXL345 shows non-zero acceleration value when idle

Tags: python, pi-3b+

I am using an ADXL345 accelerometer connected to a Raspberry Pi 3B+.I have written a python code to check the acceleration value. However, the accelerometer always shows a non-zero value for the x and y axes and a constant value for the z-axis even when stationary. Doesn't seem to be an error of the code as I have taken it from the documentation. I am a beginner so any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SPI or I2C? SPI is not 0,0 mode. Perhaps you can show us your code.

Comment: Is it showing gravity? You may need to cancel that out.

Comment: No code - can't check the code.  No photo - can't check the connections.  No results - can't check the results.  The z-axis should show 1g when stationary (the force created by the surface it is resting on).